# R reticulate install python packages

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I'm not able to install python packages via reticulate. I get following error:

```
virtualenv_install('r-reticulate', 'numpy')

Using virtual environment 'r-reticulate' ...
Error: invalid version specification ‘’, ‘  ’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system2(python, c("-c", shQuote(command)), stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) :
  running command ''/home/xxxxxxxxx/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/python' -c 'import sys; import pip; sys.stdout.write(pip.__version__)' 2>&1' had status 1
2: In if (idx != -1) version <- substring(version, 1, idx - 1) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I have created virtual environment and that can be found.

```
virtualenv_list()
[1] "r-reticulate"
```

Any ideas how to find out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To work with python in RStudio I have setted the environment through conda.

First in my R chunk:

```
install.packages("reticulate")
library(reticulate)
```

Then still in a R chunk:

```
#create the r-reticulate environment
conda_create=("r-reticulate")
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON ="path where env is located")
#Installing python libraries through conda
conda_install("r-reticulate", "numpy")
```

Now in a python script or chunk you can call normally the library by:

```
import numpy
```